# How to retrieve data which is not present in any field of one table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to retrieve a data which is not present in any field from `Table1`

**For example**
I have two table

**1. #tempLastSold**

**2. ItemRelation**

**#tempLastSold records**

```
ID      ExtendedDescription  StoreID
160641  FA012                1400      //ID present in ID of ItemRelation 
160641  FA012                2001      //ID present in ID of ItemRelation 
160632  FA003                1400      //ID present in ChildID3 of ItemRelation 
160632  FA003                2001      //ID present in ChildID3 of ItemRelation 
156824  25298                2001      //ID present in ID of ItemRelation 
158430  161-18-132           1302      //ID present in ChildID2 of ItemRelation
```

> **Note** Id of **#tempLastSold** may present in any field (may be **ID,ChildID1,ChildID2,ChildID3)** of **ItemRelation Table**

**ItemRelation records**

```
ID       ChildID1       ChildID2       ChildID3
160641   160642         Null           Null
160631   160634         160633         160632       
156824   Null           Null           Null 
158433   158431         158430         Null 
1        1A             1B             1C
2        2A             2B             2C
2        3A             3B             3C
```

I wants to display the records of **ItemRelation** which is not present in **#tempLastSold**

**#tempLastSold** having millions of records,

**ItemRelation** having 30 thousands recorsds

I tried this code

```
select ir.ID,
    ir.ItemLookupCode,
    ir.ChildID1,
    ir.ChildItemLookupCode1,
    ir.ChildID2,
    ir.ChildItemLookupCode2,
    ir.ChildID3,
    ir.ChildItemLookupCode
FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[ItemRelation] ir
left join #tempLastSold tLs on tLs.ID != ir.id 
left join #tempLastSold tLs1 on tLs1.ID !=ir.ChildID1 
left join #tempLastSold tLs2 on tLs2.ID !=ir.ChildID2
left join #tempLastSold tLs3 on tLs3.ID != ir.ChildID3
```

But it retrieved the records more than 60,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single `left join`:

```
select ir.ID,    
    ir.ChildID1,    
    ir.ChildID2,   
    ir.ChildID3
from [dbo].[ItemRelation] ir
  left join #tempLastSold tLs 
    on tLs.ID = ir.id 
    or tLs.ID = try_convert(int,ChildID1) 
    or tLs.ID = try_convert(int,ChildID2)
    or tLs.ID = try_convert(int,ChildID3)
where tls.id is null;
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/SBA83066

returns:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| ID | ChildID1 | ChildID2 | ChildID3 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 1A       | 1B       | 1C       |
|  2 | 2A       | 2B       | 2C       |
|  2 | 3A       | 3B       | 3C       |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

---

using `not exists()` instead, same result

```
select ir.ID,    
    ir.ChildID1,    
    ir.ChildID2,   
    ir.ChildID3
from [dbo].[ItemRelation] ir
where not exists (
  select 1
  from #tempLastSold tLs 
  where tLs.ID = ir.id 
     or tLs.ID = try_convert(int,ChildID1) 
     or tLs.ID = try_convert(int,ChildID2)
     or tLs.ID = try_convert(int,ChildID3)
    )
```

Comment: SqlZim It's getting slow process because of convertion. What we can do for better performance?

Comment: @mohamedfaiz which version of sql server are you using? -- if you are in 2012+, use `try_convert()` on the `ChildID`s instead of the `tLs.ID`

Comment: Sql server 2012.

Comment: error:`'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: no need to convert. Because in my records all are integer. Your query is correct. I checked the above query of the one who answered on the page rextester.com. That was wrong. If you can plz down vote it.

Comment: @mohamedfaiz Oh your example didn't have all integer, so that's why my answer had the `convert()`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select ir.*
from ItemRelation ir 
where not exists (select 1
                  from #tempLastSold tls
                  where tls.id = ir.id
                 ) or
      (ir.childid1 is not null and
       not exists (select 1
                   from #tempLastSold tls
                   where tls.id = ir.childid1
                  )
      ) or
      (ir.childid2 is not null and
       not exists (select 1
                   from #tempLastSold tls
                   where tls.id = ir.childid2
                  )
      ) or
      (ir.childid3 is not null and
       not exists (select 1
                   from #tempLastSold tls
                   where tls.id = ir.childid3
                  )
      );
```

For performance, you want an index on `3tempLastSold(id)`.

You can also simplify the query as:

```
select ir.*, g.which
from ItemRelation ir cross join
     (values (id, 'id'), (childid1, 'childid1'), (childid2, 'childid2'), (childid3, 'childid3')) v(id, which)
where v.id is not null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from #tempLastSold tls
                  where tls.id = ir.id
                 );
```

This easily shows you which column is missing.

EDIT:

You can also express this using `left join`.  The logic is a little tricky.  You need to look for a match and then see where no match occurs.  For the `id` column, this looks like:

```
select ir.*
from ItemRelation ir left join
     #tempLastSold tls
     on tls.id = ir.id
where tls.id is null;
```

Your version will find a match for all non-`NULL` values, because there will always be a record in `tls` that doesn't match the given (non-`NULL`) value.

Comment: yes you correct. But what's wrong in my code?. Can you tell me

Comment: your last query making difference from your first query

Comment: your query is wrong i think. Your first and 3 rd query making difference in retrieving records

Comment: @mohamedfaiz . . . It doesn't look wrong to me and your generic comment is entirely not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use not in

```
select * from #tempLastSold where ID not in (select id from ItemRelation Union all Select childid1 from ItemRelation union all Select childid2 from itemrelation union all select childid3 from ItemRelation )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear you want to retrieve something that no longer exists at table number 1?
By table number 2?
Or do you want Table 1 to copy to Table 2 by certain information?

Comment: Then how others can answer?