# How to use NOT EXISTS in SQL Server in my case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to retrieve some data from one table which is not present in another table.

`#tempLastSold` table records (actual records 3000)

```
ItemID
------
9
41
43
45
65
68
79
5773
5834
5838
```

`ItemRelation` table records (actual records 30,000)

```
ID     ChildID1     ChildID2     ChildID3
------------------------------------------
9      null         null          null
49     43           50                       //43 in childid1, don't want this record too
111    112          113           null
65     68           null          null
222    221          223           224
79     null         null          null
5773   5834         5838          null
```

I want to get the record from `ItemRelation` table records, which is not contain any of the values in any field from `#tempLastSold`

Expected output:

```
ID     ChildID1     ChildID2     ChildID3
------------------------------------------
111    112          113           null
222    221          223           224
```

I tried this one

```
select id 
from ItemRelation
where not exists (select ir.id 
                  from ItemRelation ir
                  inner join #tempLastSold ls on ls.ItemID = ir.ID 
                                              or ls.ItemID = ir.ChildID1
                                              or ls.ItemID = ir.ChildID2
                                              or ls.ItemID = ir.ChildID3)
```

I am not sure whether my query is correct or wrong. But it still loading and it cross 3 min

But it's keep on loading. because `Itemrelation` table has 30K records. But I think it is very small number of records

Comment: Have you tried repeatedly LEFT JOINing `ItemRelation` with `#tempLastSold`?

Comment: May I know why negative marks?

Comment: Do you mean that this statement returns more records than what you expect? Can you post a couple of them?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis sorry i don't understand what are you trying to say?

Comment: What is the return result of the statement you tried? Is it as expected (but slow)? Or does it return more records than expected?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis I tried that query, But it doesn't bring me any records until 2 min, it's keep on loading. I am not sure whether it is right or wrong

Comment: OK, give me a couple of minutes, I am trying to check it.

Comment: GiorgosAltanis ok

Comment: I am afraid that it won't return anything!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139071/discussion-between-mohamed-faiz-and-giorgos-altanis).

Comment: No need to, you already have two answers (one in the path you were trying, the other with LEFT JOINS), I think you will be OK.

Comment: Same question by same user with different sample data - Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data which is not present in any field of one table in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016496/how-to-retrieve-data-which-is-not-present-in-any-field-of-one-table-in-sql-serve)

Comment: @Sqlzim No, It's not duplicate question, both question is asked by me. Both are different criteria. read that link question completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `NOT EXISTS` without an inner join, it is recommended more than `NOT IN` or `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

```
select id 
from ItemRelation ir
where not exists (
select 1
from  #tempLastSold ls 
WHERE ls.ItemID in (ir.ID, ir.ChildID1, ir.ChildID2, ir.ChildID3)
) AND ir.id is NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is that `select 1`?

Comment: Select 1 is used to check if the query return a value, it is not necessary to retrun all columns

Comment: it is for performance issue, the query in `NOT EXISTS` clause is used only to check whether it returns values or not

Comment: Your link was interesting, but look what I found in the summary: "In SQL Server, NOT EXISTS and NOT IN predicates are the best way to search for missing values, as long as both columns in question are NOT NULL", clearly this does not apply here.

Comment: it is simple just add a NOT NULL condition in the where clause

Comment: @Hadi I don't object to your answer, it was good enough even without the addition of NOT NULL, so I have upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it [works on your sample data](http://rextester.com/JUGQ42589):

```
select ir.*
from ItemRelation ir 
left join #tempLastSold t1 on ir.ID = t1.ItemID
left join #tempLastSold t2 on ir.ChildID1 = t2.ItemID
left join #tempLastSold t3 on ir.ChildID2 = t3.ItemID
left join #tempLastSold t4 on ir.ChildID3 = t4.ItemID
where t1.ItemID is null and t2.ItemID is null and t3.ItemID is null and t4.ItemID is null
```

Comment: it is not recommeded to use `LEFT JOIN` https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: I have commented in your answer, first of all "not recommended by whom". Moreover, even the summary of your link states the assumptions, which are not valid in our case... Anyway, thanks for your efforts to educate :-)